# How to solve mousemove event bug in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I give `mouseup` `mousedown` `mousemove` different event handler:

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");

body.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
    console.log("mouseup");
});

body.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    console.log("mousedown");
});

body.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
    console.log("mousemove");
})
```

when I click right mouse button, open the context menu, without mouse move, it will trigger the mouse move event,

the more strange thing is, if I open the context menu again, event the mouse down event couldn't be trigger, could only trigger the mouse move event

http://jsfiddle.net/WZSva/

How can I solve this problem?